# Converting a postgresql array to a set

Tags: postgresql, set

I'm using the (nifty!) `string_agg` function in `postgresql` to accumulate values of a given field

```
string_agg(r.pmid, ',' order by pmid)
```

This gives results like this - due to duplicate values of id's in underlying data:

```
15364708,15364708,15364708,15364709,15364709,15364709
```

How can this `array` / `list` be converted to a `set` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `DISTINCT` with `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT r.pmid, ',' ORDER BY pmid)
FROM yourTable
...
```

Comment: ah so the first portion of the function call can have _bona fide_ sql constructs - neat!

Comment: @javadba Yes...it looks and feels a bit weird at first, but you get used to it ^ ^

Comment: 7 minutes, tic toc